# is OpenAPIDeserializer.java memory efficient to parse json node into OpenAPI

Tags: java, kubernetes, openapi, swagger-2.0, swagger-3.0

I am reading very small yaml files (3 kb to 330 kb) , converting into the JsoneNode and then converting it into OpenAPI objects, while I am deploying my code on a k8 setup, I can see huge memory spike like 500-600 MB during the below code run: ,

String content =  ClasspathHelper.loadFileFromClasspath("test.yaml");

final JsonNode jsonNode = JSON_MAPPER_FOR_YAML.readTree(content); //here JSON_MAPPER_FOR_YAML = ObjectMapperFactory.createYaml();

OpenAPI openAPI = new OpenAPIDeserializer().deserialize(jsonNode, path, new ParseOptions())

//Earlier ,I had tried below option as well but of no use in terms of memory spikes

OpenAPI openAPI = new OpenAPIV3Parser().parseJsonNode("/" + "test.yaml", jsonNode).getOpenAPI()

Trying to understand how such small yaml files can cause 500-600 MB memory spikes .
I dont see such memory spikes when I run the same code in intellij and use jprofiler to see the memory .

Any one has any idea?

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-parser/blob/master/modules/swagger-parser-v3/src/main/java/io/swagger/v3/parser/util/OpenAPIDeserializer.java

Comment: I can see below jvm args that being used:
 spec:
      containers:
      - args:
        - --enable-preview
        - -Xmx6144m
        - -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=20
        - -XX:SurvivorRatio=10
        - -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=32m
        - -XX:+OptimizeStringConcat
        - -Xss256k
        - -XX:TargetSurvivorRatio=90
        - -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=16
        - -XX:+UseG1GC
        - -XX:+UseStringDeduplication
        - -jar
        - abc.jar
        - -XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages

Comment: does anyone have any idea?